# Loose wires in 1993 5.0 V8 F150 Engine

Tags: engine, ford, f-150, connector

I have acquired this very used truck. It seemed to be able to run (albeit by burning transmission and coolant, but that's a different thread) but I wanted to ask if anyone could ID these wires? I could not find a port for them to attach to. It looks like they are coming off that thick cable of wires.

[image: Drivers side of engine]

Two more pictures from this morning.

[image: Front view]

[image: View from drivers side]

Comment: Think you can trace the cable and post more pictures?

Comment: Added two pictures. I tried to feel around for connectors or clipped wires where these loose ones would go, but no dice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think @Zaid is correct on the first one (A/C). The second one, however, I believe is actually the Power Steering Pressure Sensor (PSPS) Connector, which uses the same pig tail as the injector harness, but would account for the good running engine. (Motorcraft part number WPT372)

**EDIT:**

Looking at the new pictures, it appears the upper pulley replaces an A/C compressor (looks like no A/C in the truck ... this is called an *idler pulley* which just takes up the space of an A/C compressor so they don't have to re-engineer things), so the A/C plug would not be used.

Secondly, looking at the power steering pump (a new one from an online parts catalog) I see that there is *supposed to be* a PSPS on the pump (due to them offering one in the catalog), but I don't see a provision for it on the pump itself. You'd be looking for something like this:

[image]

It may be since you don't have A/C in the truck, this vehicle is more of a *work truck*, which is designed not to have all the bells and whistles. It's just designed to do the job. If so, what happens is, they will only make one wiring harness for the full line of F-150 trucks which covers the use of an A/C unit and the PSPS, but sinse your truck doesn't have these, the plugs aren't connected to anything or just left hanging free.

Comment: That is the power steering on the bottom and AC compressor above it, right?

Comment: @Slobvrflw - Please see **EDIT:**

Comment: @Slobvrflw - Sorry I didn't answer your comment directly. In the bottom picture of the three you posted ... the top wire would be for the A/C and the bottom wire would be for the PSPS. Same as the order which Zaid showed them in his thread.

Answer (score 5):

Given its proximity to the AC compressor, the one to the left appears to be the wire for the AC compressor clutch; the connector looks similar to the one for a [brand-new replacement](https://www.ronfrancis.com/products.asp?dept=296&pagenumber=2&sort_on=&sort_by=):

[image: AC Clutch wire]

---

I'm speculating that the one on the right side of the picture is a [fuel injector connector](http://www.fordparts.com/Commerce/PartDetail.aspx?n=u8ykr%2fx8AWrUcw%2bdMmQAxw%3d%3d&id=316243093&m=2&search=true&year=1993&make=Ford&model=F-150), a clearer picture from a different angle would help:

[image: fuel injector connector]

Comment: That's some mighty fine detective work. I'd agree with you on the A/C connector, wholeheartedly. The other one, while matching the look exactly, I'd have an issue saying it is an injector harness. If it were, the OP would have a dead cylinder, which doesn't sound like the case from the description of how the engine runs.